# Missing title in template for custom route

Tags: theming, routes

I'm missing a title `(_title)` being shown on a custom route page. I wonder where i can place it in a template for it to show up.

My route:

```
bg_helper.blogs_overview:
  path: '/blog'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\bg_helper\Controller\DefaultListController::overview'
    _title: 'Blog'
    type: 'blog'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And the overview method:

```
class DefaultListController extends ControllerBase {
  public function overview($type, $language = false) {
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $query->condition('type', $type);
    $query->pager(10);
    $nids = $query->execute();

    $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

    $build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->viewMultiple($nodes, 'teaser');
    $build['pager'] = [
      '#type' => 'pager',
    ];
    return $build;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You find the `_title` default in the route object of the current route match, which you get by using a type-hinted argument in the controller method:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;

...

  public function page(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t($route_match->getRouteObject()->getDefault('_title')),
    ];
  }
```

For multilingual sites use `$this->t()` to translate the title. In more advanced cases with placeholders in the title use [`TitleResolver::getTitle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Controller%21TitleResolver.php/function/TitleResolver%3A%3AgetTitle/8.4.x).